# Chain calls to the same function and modify an internal variable

Tags: javascript, chaining

Is this possible with javascript? Use the same function and call it again and again.

`myFunc("test")("me")("please")()`

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answers. I'd like to keep and internal variable that appends the string to the previous one if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function MyFunc(arg){
    console.log(arg);
    return MyFunc;
}

MyFunc("a")("b")("c");
```

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kZKrq/7/)

[Y-combinator](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Y_combinator#JavaScript) example:

```
function Y(f) {
    var g = f(function() {
        return g.apply(this, arguments);
    });
    return g;
}

var MyFunc = Y(function(f) {
    var a = "";
    return function(n) {
        a = a + n;
        console.log(a);
        return f;
    };
});

//alert(a); // throws error as a is outside of scope here
MyFunc("a")("b")("c"); # logs a; ab; abc
```

Comment: that almost does what I want. Could you check my edit?

Comment: That's cool. Can the same be done by returning an anonymous function?

Comment: @user3006500 I believe it is using `argument.callee` as @Benio suggested. Or, if you're a big fan of functional programming and λ-calculus, using a fixed-point combinator (aka [Y-combinator](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Y_combinator#JavaScript))

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, if you will `return arguments.callee;`, example:

```
(function(param){console.log(param); return arguments.callee;})("test")("me")("please")
```

will log into console:

```
test
me
please
```

Comment: Named function expressions are preferd over `callee`. `function f (a) { console.log(a); return f; }`